# What's the best design in tracking the remaining inventory of a product in a store

Tags: algorithm, database-design

Sorry if the title is confusing, I'll just try to describe here I want to achieve.

I want to optimize my database design that handles delivery, and ending inventory. Delivery is done anytime of the week and is group by week number, orders can be done anytime of the day; orders quantity are then subtracted to the total no of delivery per week to get the ending inventory. What's the best database design for this, and programming approach?

```
What I have:
Deliveries table with quantity, weekNo, weekYr
Orders table with quantity, weekNo, weekYr
```

Everytime I want to get the ending inventory I will get and group the data base on weekYr and weekNo and subtract total Deliveries quantity minus Orders quantity. But my problem is the ending inventory will be carried out to the next week. What's the best and optimized way to do it?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach seems sound to me, so you might clarify what the actual problem is.  Your last sentence is confusing--does the product spoil at the end of the week?  It's not clear why you would need to group by week at all.  If you get 100 products via delivery, and sell 10 products per week for the next three weeks, you have 70 products left.

My best guess is you have a case where there are other factors to consider besides the simple math of what was received minus what was sold.  Perhaps you lose inventory due to spoilage (maybe you sell some sort of food) or shrinkage (maybe you sell retail goods that get stolen).  One solution would be to have a separate table called "shrinkage" or "spoilage" that also gets subtracted out of deliveries to arrive at your actual inventory.  Of course, this table will need to be updated as product is removed from the shelves due to spoilage, or when the shrinkage is realized.

Comment: Hi, actually clients wants to monitor the delivery vs sales per week so it's more of a business rule. Every week they want a report of how many are delivered to the store and how many were sold. And yes there are other factors like returns (defective items), which I'm storing in a separate table also per week. My concern is for example for the 50th week to find how many are in the remaining inventory I need to sum all the delivered items from week 1-49th minus total no of orders in the same week span. I think I can do that but is that the best approach?

Comment: I tried creating a table where I save the ending inventory for the week per branch, per sku. Unfortunately every week I have noOfBranch x noOfSku x 52 (weeks). Which will cost me millions of records in just a year, so I guess it's not the right approach. But I don't want to compute the ending inventory (totalDelivery-totalReturns-totalSold) each time. Is there no other way to work on this?